Expand variable containing commands within 'osascript -e' construct
I'm attempting to write a function within zsh that takes input 1 (in this case, an arbitrary set of commands) and executes those commands in a new shell. I have the following so far:
 function () { osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "echo hello world" ' }
This opens a new shell and prints "hello world". I want to replace "echo hello world" with "$1", like so:
 function () { osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "$1" ' }
However, this just prints $1 in the new terminal without actually expanding the variable.
Thanks in advance!
I've tried a few different combinations of escape characters, single/double quotes, etc. For further reference, I'm attempting to run an ssh command with more commands embedded within the ssh command.

Don't generate the AppleScript dynamically using string interpolation. Write a parameterized AppleScript which takes "$1" as its argument, something like osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script <something>' "$1".

(See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258142/how-can-i-open-applescript-app-with-arguments#29266283)

A simplified set of quoting rules to keep in mind when building strings:

Only the outer pairs of quotes matter.
Variables and wildcards and such are not expanded inside single quotes.
Variables ($something) are expanded inside double quotes.
Adjacent strings are concatenated.

We can use the last rule to build a longer string out of separate pieces that have different quoting. The string in the print statement here has just three pairs of quotes. The ones that are actually used by the shell for quoting are indicated with a ^ underneath, the others are just part of the text:
=> var=TEXT
=> print -r -- '[in single "quotes" $$]'"_''_${var}__"'[etc """ ${var}]'
=> :           ^                       ^^            ^^                ^
[in single "quotes" $$]_''_TEXT__[etc """ ${var}]

The same technique can be used in your function. Note that this uses a different function name; function is a reserved word:
runOsaScript() {
  osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "'"$1"'"'
}

